# is $H^2\subset L^{\infty}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Is the space of function $H^2$ subset of the space $L^{\infty}$ on any set (such as $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}_+$)?

Is there a reference for the proof?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is a bit vague, I can only give a rather vague answer. In general, in order to determine if a Sobelev function is in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a not necesarrily bounded subset, is usually done via the Morrey estimate
$$
||u||_{C^{0,\gamma}(\Omega)}\leq C||u||_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}
$$
for $p>n$. In order to get the $p$ "high enough", you can use the Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality inequality to show that
$$
||u||_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}\leq C ||u||_{H^2(\Omega)} 
$$
for some suitable value of $p>2$. Depending on $n$, you can check for which dimensions your function is Hölder and then you have to consider many cases. For example, if $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, then your Hölder function is in $C(\overline{\Omega)})$ and therefore bounded (i.e. in $L^{\infty}(\Omega))$. For unbounded domains, like the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, you have to work a bit harder. If I remember correctly, square integrable Hölder functions tend to $0$ as $|x| \to \infty$, but I dont have a reference at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. However, I cannot know if my function is Holder or not. I only know that it is $L^2$ integrable.

Comment: Morrey estimates tell you that Sobolev functions are automatically Hölder if your exponent in $W^{1,p}$ is high enough. This is the case when $p>n$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you!

Comment: I was also a bit stuck when I first encountered this. Instead of considering arbitrary sets, just look at how it is on bounded domains and after that how it is on the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$. Generally speaking, something in between, like upper half-planes, usually makes it harder to understand to what is "really going on".